# "…to the end that a blessed status be attained in the future world…" — If we replaced "be" with "will be", would the sentence meaning remain the same?

Tags: subjunctives, subordinate-clauses

As far as I understand, after "*to the end that*", we can use both the subjunctive and indicative.
Is it true?

an example from [a book](https://www.google.ru/books/edition/From_Irenaeus_to_Grotius/fv-AEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to%20the%20end%20that%20a%22&pg=PA430&printsec=frontcover):

> As teachers of this law, and as ministers of its sacraments, certain men in the communities were chosen, called priests and deacons or Levites. It is their office to teach the commands and counsels of the Christian evangelical law, as to what must be believed, done and spurned, **to the end that** a blessed status **be** attained in the future world, and the opposite avoided.

from the text:
**(1)** *… to the end that a blessed status **be** attained in the future world …*
my variant:
**(2)** *… to the end that a blessed status **will be** attained in the future world …*

Is (2) correct too?
If not, then why not?
If it is, then what is the difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: Bare **be** is a mandative form there. Both forms are grammatical. You could also use **would be** or **shall be**.  The difference is that mandative **be** marks it as an end goal or purpose and **will be** does not. **will be** expresses it  as an unavoidable or necessary outcome, and so there is a hint of a semantic clash between "to the end" and "will" that must be resolved.  At least for speakers who use the mandative. For those speakers that never use it, it's just an old-fashioned way of talking with no semantic nuance.

Comment: It is just as @TimRonsomedevice explains. An example where the difference might be clearer is *The Governor has ordered that flags **be** flown at half staff for thirty days*. Using ***will** be* there would sound wrong, to me anyway. One orders that something **be** done, not that something ***will** be* done. But I suppose some speakers don’t make the distinction. How sad, that Western Civilization should have reached such a state of decay.

Comment: Note too that the tone of the passage you quote is formal, and somewhat Biblical. So the mandative *be* is a better fit than your proposed rewrite.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum You say "_The Governor has ordered that flags **will** be flown at half staff for thirty days._" sounds wrong to you. Is that because a content clause after the verb "_order_" can be only mandative?

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice You say "will be" creates a semantic clash between "to the end" and "will" that must be resolved. I can't understand what you mean by the phrase "that must be resolved". How can it be resolved? Could you explain it to me please?

Comment: @Lovii.  The bare form of the verb BE in your subjunctive example "to the end that a blessed status be attained in the future world" expresses not a guaranteed future but a *sought* or *desired* future, whereas **will be** doesn't have that nuance.